# Re-sort sql after results already generated

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Is there a way to resort a mySQL sql after the results are already generated.

I have a sql that gets the results I want to display basically but the way I want to sort them depends on the result themselves. Have provided some pseudo code for clarity.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE poster = 'login_user' OR replier = 'login_user'";

if ('login_user' == $row['poster']) { //sort by one column } 
else { //sort by a different column }
```

Comment: just sudo code.. my actual code is more complex but if I can figure out how to do something like above I will be able to figure out to make it work for my actual code also..

Comment: why do you have to do another sorting after the values have been fetched? its still much better to do some sort when do it in your query, just append your custom sort before you actually perform the query, not after

Comment: basically i have a posterRead or a replierRead column.. I want to sort results first by the "read/not read" and then by date.. finding it hard to do this when I want all the results as the same group.. I am newish to mysql commands.

Comment: order by case.. never heard of that.. I will look into it but it sounds like you have my solution. Thanks.

Comment: I sense an answer coming, given a now-deleted comment about CASE. Edit: [*Yep, I was right*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39029550/) - "Spidey sense at work" ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort conditionally from within the query with a `CASE` statement.

```
ORDER BY (CASE
  WHEN poster = 'login_user' THEN col1
  ELSE col2
END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT *, if(poster='login_user', 1, 0) as idx FROM post_info WHERE poster = 'login_user' OR replier = 'login_user' order by idx desc";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE poster = 'login_user' UNION SELECT * FROM post_info WHERE replier = 'login_user'";
```